# Thread safe database access in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a Winforms application that does some hefty database work. It does a lot of reading and some inserting of records. The operation can take up to 30 seconds to a minute, depending on the size of the database. Right now, my program works just fine.

My problem is, while my program is doing this, my UI thread is being blocked till the database stuff is done. I'd like to put the database functions into a thread, however, according to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx#adonetbest_topic7), ADO.NET is not thread-safe.

Is there a way to provide a progress bar on my UI or some way around the "ADO.NET is not thread safe"? Maybe to write my own classes that inherit `SqlDataReader` or `SqlConnection` to make it thread-safe. Is this even possible?

Comment: Which Database? Access has a different set of problems than MS-SQL.

Comment: @HenkHolterman -- It actually works across three different database servers, SQL Server 2000, Microsoft Access and MySQL.

Comment: That could complicate things. How do you handle keys, could they become GUIDs ?

Comment: Henk, the tables in my SQL Server 2000 database are integers and they have identities, so SQL Server should take care of that. For the MS Access and MySQL, I will NOT be doing CRUD on those. Only SELECT queries. Does this simplify things more?

Comment: Yes, that should solve all Key issues.

Comment: So Henk, given all this information, if I put my database processing task in a `BackgroundWorker` thread, I should have no weird issues? Assuming each thread opens and closes the connection with its own Connection object?

Comment: And as long as your Bgw.DoWork() doesn't touch the GUI. Use Completed() for Databinding.

Comment: Yeah, the database stuff is actually being done from a sister DLL file. This DLL doesn't even know about a GUI, so that definitely shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a backgroundworker and make sure each thread (bgw) creates its own Connection object.

And regarding to the linked article, make sure you have a Concurrency-safe way of generating keys. Letting the Db generate them is the best option.

> Is there a way to provide a progress bar on my UI

That's tricky. A Bgw can ReportProgress just fine but getting it from a running query is a problem. Even the total nr of rows is usually only known at the end.
But you can always fake it, the user doesn't mind/know.